# Which contentplaceholder to use for Search Center

Tags: 2010, search, master-page

In my SharePoint site I am using a custom masterpage which is based on the original v4 masterpage. I did not make any big changes, except add a line to use custom CSS.

However when I create a Search Center using the Basic search site template and then add my custom masterpage, the search box dissapears.

Below are two images to demonstrate my problem :

This image demonstrates how the site looks after I use my custom master page, in the red square you can see the line of an ill sized part of the page.
[As it is http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4521/error1sj.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4521/error1sj.png)

This image demonstrates how the site should look, and then I mean the search box being present. 
[As it should be http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/6398/error2sq.png](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/6398/error2sq.png)

So my question is what is the cause of this problem and if I am missing a contentplaceholder, then which one is it?

**edit**
So as PirateEric said, the Search center inherits from the minimal.master so that is causing this weird layout. I would like to make it possible to use just one master page for all sharepoint site. So my question is which contentplaceholders do i need to make this happen?

All help and comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the search center uses the minimal.master not v4 like the parent.  If all you've done to the portal master page is change the CSS, then you can do the same process for the search center (copy minimal.master, rename, and CSS reference) or just apply the CSS file through the UI (if applicable).

Comment: Just as you posted this i stumbled onto this, the problem however is that i also want just one masterpage for all my SharePoint sites. Can i rebuild my masterpage and add the needed placeholders? and then which placeholders are these, thanks for your answer